# Handling undefined/null properties in components during first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and it's great, but i've ran into an issue and i'm not sure what the best practice is to solve it.

I'm fetching data from an API in my componentDidMount(), then i'm setting some states with SetState().

Now the problem is that because the first render happens before my states have been set, im sending the initial state values into my components. Right now i'm setting them to empty arrays or empty Objects ({ type: Object, default: () => ({}) }).
Then i'm using ternary operator to check the .length or if the property has a value.

Is this the best practice or is there some other way that i'm unaware of?

I would love to get some help with this, so that i do the basics correctly right from the start.

Thanks!

Comment: It's generally better if you include your code in the question instead of just describing  it in text. What you are outlining sounds like one of many good solutions, but it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: What you're doing is fine. I usually either have the state empty and return early like `if (!state.something) return <p>Loading...</p>` or set state to default values that match the correct type, e.g. empty strings or empty arrays, so the component can still render fine but then stuff can pop in after an update.

Comment: A common pattern is to initialize state in your class constructor with a `loaded` property which you would set to true when your API request returns in `componentDidMount`. If it's false, you can show a loading spinner or something. If it's true, you render the data from your request. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best practice is to tell the user that your data is still loading, then populate the fields with the real data. This approach has been advocated in various blog-posts. Robin Wieruch has a great write up on how to fetch data, with a [specific example](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/#react-fetch-data-loading-error) on how to handle loading data and errors and I will go through his example here. This approach is generally done in two parts.

1. Create an `isLoading` variable. This is a `bolean`. We initially set it to `false`, because nothing is loading, then set it to `true` when we try to fetch the data, and then back to `false` once the data is loaded.
2. We have to tell React what to render given the two `isLoading` states.

### 1. Setting the isLoading variable

Since you did not provide any code, I'll just follow Wieruch's example.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataFromApi: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.mydomain.com')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ dataFromApi: data.dataFromApi }));
  }

  ...
}

export default App;
```

Here we are using the browser's [native `fetch()` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get the data when the component mounts via the use of `componentDidMount()`. This should be quite similar to what you are doing now. Given that the `fetch()` method is asynchronous, the rest of the page will render and the state will be up dated once the data is received.

In order to tell the user that we are waiting for data to load, we simply add `isLoading` to our state. so the state becomes:

```
this.state = {
  dataFromApi: null,
  isLoading: false,
};
```

The state for `isLoading` is initially `false` because we haven't called `fetch()` yet. Right before we call `fetch()` inside `componentDidMount()` we set the state of `isLoading` to true, as such:

```
this.setState({ isLoading: true });
```

We then need to add a then() method to our `fetch()` Promise to set the state of `isLoading` to `false`, once the data has finished loading.

```
.then(data => this.setState({ dataFromAPi: data.dataFromApi, isLoading: false }));
```

The final code looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataFromApi: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    fetch('https://api.mydomain.com')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ dataFromApi: data.dataFromApi, isLoading: false }));
  }

  ...
}

export default App;
```

### 2. Conditional Rendering

React allows for [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). We can use a simple `if` statement in our `render()` method to render the component based on the state of `isLoading`.

```
class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const { hits, isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    }

    return (
      <ul>
        {dataFromApi.map(data =>
          <li key={data.objectID}>
            <a href={data.url}>{data.title}</a>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks really great, thank you for the thorough explanation! I've been using ternary mostly by checking for null or length, but your example with a boolean makes the code a bit easier to read. Will definitely try your method out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

It Depends.
suppose you are fetching books data from server.
here is how to do that.

```js
state = {
  books: null,
}
```

if, your backend api is correctly setup.
You will get either empty array for no books or array with some length

```js
componentDidMount(){
    getBooksFromServer().then(res => {
     this.setState({
     books: res.data
   })
  })
 }
```

Now In Your render method

```js
   render() {
         const { books } = this.state;
         let renderData;
         if(!books) {
          renderData = <Spinner />
      } else
        if(books.length === 0) {
        renderData = <EmptyScreen />
       }
      else {
     renderData = <Books data = { books } />
   }
   
   return renderData;
   }
```

If you are using offline data persistence In that case initially you won't have empty array.So This way of handling won't work.
To show the spinner you have to keep a variable **loader** in state.
and set it true before calling api and make it false when promise resolves or rejects.

finally read upon to state.

```js
   const {loader} = this.state;
   if(loader) {
   renderData = <Spinner />
}
```

Comment: This is the way i've been doing it and it's worked out great, thank you. I found pooya72's answer really good as well, he had a slightly different approach that i hadn't thought of. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

I set initial state in constructor. You can of course set initial state of component as static value - empty array or object. I think better way is to set it using props. Therefore you can use you component like so `<App items={[1,2,3]} />` or `<App />` (which takes value of items from `defaultProps` object because you not pass it as prop).

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                items: [], // or items: {...props.items} 
            };



        }
        async componentDidMount() {
            const res = await this.props.getItems();
            this.setState({items: res.data.items})
        }
        render() {
               return <div></div>
           }
};

App.defaultProps = {
items: []
}
```